Is it possible to copy a text file (not the content), from the browser?
Let's say when we copy an image from the browser, it copies it as an image/png.
I know I can copy text using navigator.clipboard.write("Some text").
Now is it possible to copy an actual file like:

something.txt with a content of "Some text".

Use case: Seamless copy from browser, then paste into VSCode. For images this seems to be possible.

If not, maybe a drag and drop flow? In Mac, I can drag an image from the browser to "Finder", and it downloads the image exactly there. How can I do that with a .txt file?

That’d be a huge security risk

Thanks for answering @DanielA.White. Just curious if it was possible. :)
